# Classification with Augmentation vs Contrastive Learning

Tags: neural-networks, computer-vision

How Contrastive Learning based on (**SimCLRv2** approach) is compared to regular classification  (VGG, Resnset, etc) with Data Augmentation.

It seems to me, that it should have very similar performance.
I'm wrong?

What are the advantages of Contrastive learning  (SimCLR approach) ?

[image: Model based on SimCLR approach]

[Big Self-Supervised Models are Strong Semi-Supervised Learners](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.10029)

Answer (score 0):

The main advantage of contrastive learning is that you don't need labels to train a model. You should use it for tasks where getting labeled examples is hard, expensive or inconvenient.

The self-supervised workflow usually works in 2 phases:

1. Pretext task - You train a model with unlabeled examples using a contrastive loss (SimCLR, MOCO, BYOL, Barlow Twins or similar). You usually have access to a large amount of unlabeled examples.
2. Downstream task - This is actually the task that you want to solve. You need to have some labeled examples, usually it is much smaller amount than you need for pretext task. The model is intialized with weight from a  pre-trained model, usually you fix most of the weights and train a few linear layers on top the pretrained model. Or fine-tuning of larger part of the model can be used.

Comment: What is the advantage over taking the network trained on imagenet and fine-tune it with "some labeled examples" with augmentation ?

Comment: If the data you want to use as inputs are very similar to ImageNet data there is probably no benefit of self-supervised learning. Although if the distribution of your data is different (manufacturing images, infrared camera, specific light, medical images) then pre-training on the data from your distribution will probably be better. And for this you can use self-supervised learning if labelling is expensive.